# Cancel all pending http request with Angular Interceptor

Tags: angular, http, request, httpclient, interceptor

My interceptor:

```
constructor(router: Router,
        private httpCancelService: HttpCancelService) {
        router.events.subscribe(event => {
            if (event instanceof ActivationEnd) {
                this.httpCancelService.cancelPendingRequests();
            }
        });
    }

    intercept<T>(req: HttpRequest<T>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<T>> {
        return next.handle(req).pipe(takeUntil(this.httpCancelService.onCancelPendingRequests()));
    }
```

My cancel service:

```
 private pendingHTTPRequests$ = new Subject<void>();

    constructor() { }


    public cancelPendingRequests() {
        this.pendingHTTPRequests$.next();
    }

    public onCancelPendingRequests() {
        return this.pendingHTTPRequests$.asObservable();
    }
```

It is working perfectly for me but the problem I have is that when I change the route to a route that generates several initial requests, it cancels the pending requests of my previous route and cancels the request of my current route.

**What can I do so that I only cancel the pending requests of my previous route and do not touch any request of my current route**

thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

When you navigate to the new location, the `ActivationEnd` event occurs after the component loads.
If you listen to the `NavigationStart` event you cancel all events and then the new component loads.

so your interceptor ctor should look like:

```
router.events.subscribe(event => {
     if (event instanceof NavigationStart ) {
          this.httpCancelService.cancelPendingRequests();
     }
});
```

**Important**:
It may be that the event I suggested may not suit you, take a look at the documentation and see what works best for you: https://angular.io/api/router/Event